# bcp command does not write the xml to a folder in the server, but gives no errors

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a stored procedure in SQL Server 2008 which constructs an xml. I need to write this xml to a folder in the same server. The userid I use has execute permissions. However when I run this stored procedure, there are no errors thrown, but it does not write the file in the folder.

Any ideas where I am going wrong?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[kc_comp_data_sp] 
AS 
  DECLARE 
    @company_xmlpartO nvarchar(MAX),
    @company_xmlpart nvarchar(MAX),
    @company_xml nvarchar(MAX),
    @xml_beg nvarchar(200),
    @xmlEnd nvarchar(100),
    @xml XML,
    @temp NVARCHAR(255),
    @CompName VARCHAR(255),
    @GivenName  VARCHAR(255),
    @Gender CHAR(1),
    @City VARCHAR(255),
    @State CHAR(2),
    @count int =0,
    @strbcpcmd VARCHAR(500),
    @filename varchar(70)

    SET @xml_beg = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
     <Company xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="Company.xsd">'
    SET @xmlEnd = '</Company>'
    SET @comp_xmlpartO = '<CompanyData>
        <ID></ID>
        <CompanyName><![CDATA[~fname~]]></CompanyName>     
        <GivenName><![CDATA[~lname~]]></GivenName>     
        <Addresses>
            <BillingAddress>
                <Address1></Address1>
                <Address2></Address2>
                <Address3></Address3>
                <City></City>
                <State></State>
                <ZipCode></ZipCode>
                <Fax1></Fax1>
            </BillingAddress>
          </Addresses>
      <CompanyData>'


set @company_xmlpart = @company_xmlpartO

DECLARE xml_cursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT CompanyName , GivenName 
OPEN xml_cursor 

FETCH NEXT FROM xml_cursor into @CompName, @GivennNme 

WHILE @@fetch_status = 0
BEGIN

    SET  @company_xmlpart = REPLACE(@company_xmlpart,N'~fname~',@CompName )
    SET  @customer_xmlpart = REPLACE(@company_xmlpart,N'~lname~',@GivenName  )
    if(@count > 0)
    BEGIN
       SET @company_xml = @company_xml + @company_xmlpart
    END
    else
    BEGIN
        SET @company_xm = @company_xmlpart
    END

    SET @count = @count +1
    SET  @company_xmlpart =  @company_xmlpartO

   FETCH NEXT FROM xml_cursor into @CompName, @GivenName 



END
SET  @company_xml=  @xml_beg +  @company_xml + @xmlEnd
 SET @xml = CAST(@company_xml AS XML)


 set @fileName = 'D:\Samples\compsample1.xml'

 CLOSE xml_cursor 
 DEALLOCATE xml_cursor

  set @strbcpcmd = 'bcp  "exec ' + cast(@xml as varchar(max)) + ' " queryout ' + @fileName + ' -S servernmae -U userid -P password -T -w -r -t';
  exec xp_cmdshell @strbcpcmd
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is not a SQL Server error, so it is ignored. The error is from the command shell.

The xp_cmdshell does return a Return Code Value.

```
DECLARE @result int
EXEC @result = xp_cmdshell .....
```

The output of the command shell is returned a result set.

```
DECLARE @ReturnCode INT, 
        @ErrorMessage varchar(2000)

CREATE TABLE #temp (SomeCol VARCHAR(500))
INSERT #temp
EXEC @ReturnCode = master.dbo.xp_cmdshell ....

IF @ReturnCode <> 0
BEGIN
    SELECT @ErrorMessage = @ErrorMessage + SomeCol   
    FROM #temp
    WHERE SomeCol IS NOT NULL

    SELECT @ErrorMessage as ErrorMessage, @ReturnCode as ReturnCode

END
```

Comment: Apparently, it returns a value of 1, meaning failure. Is there any way I can see the error messages?

Comment: Thanks. At least I can see my error : something about Usage. Maybe I a not using bcp the righ tway